# Flex HTTPServices and valid xml

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript, httpservice

I'm currently attempting to communicate with an API using Flex as the client.
I'm using Flash Builders HTTPServices to do so, bit of a noob to all this.
All works correctly if the accessed XML files elements are formatted correctly however if I add a hyphen to the element name I get flex warning me to the fact ie. The returned object contains an invalid name "created-on" that does not conform to the Actionscript identifier naming guidelines

This works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects type="array">
  <project>
    <createdon>2010-07-10</createdon>
    <name>Project 1</name>
  </project>
</projects>
```

This does not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects type="array">
  <project>
    <created-on>2010-07-10</created-on>
    <name>Project 1</name>
  </project>
</projects>
```

My question then is what can I do to make the returned xml actionscript friendly. Is there a standard or a best practice for this? I obviously don't have any control over the xml being passed.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, use square brackets.  For example:

```
private var createdOn:String;

protected function myService_requestHandler(event:ResultHandler):void
{
    createdOn = event.result.projects.project["created-on"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to access the content without the '-' set the resultFormat to 'text' and then do something like:

```
onLoad(event:ResultEvent):void
{
     var result:String = event.result;
     result = result.replace(/created-on/g, 'createdOn');
     var xml:XML = new XML(result);
     // do your processing now...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the [resultFormat](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#resultFormat) of `HTTPService` to `e4x` or `xml`. The default value is `object` and hence Flex tries to create ActionScript object for each elements in the xml tree.

```
<mx:HTTPService resultFormat="xml" other="attributes go here"/>
```

Comment: @Pakman I do not have Flex builder to try this, so hope you verified before down voting.

Comment: The author asked how to handle XML nodes with hyphens.  Even if you change the `resultFormat` to `e4x`, you still have to use brackets to reference the node.  But, I'm new to Flex, so I could be wrong.